# Using a congratulatory (end of proof) box properly in LyX

Tags: lyx, theorems

I know how to enter the end of proof boxes in LyX:

`\square`, `\blacksquare`. However, I don't like where it ends up in the PDF. Here's an example

[image]

I want it to mock the example below (cropped from Munkres' Topology)

[image]

How do I do this?
This is how I currently enter boxes in LyX: [image]

Comment: If you load `amsthm` you have a `proof` environment that adds the tombstone automatically. Just change the meaning of `\qedsymbol` to `$\blacksquare$`.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of how you've set it up currently (from LyX)?  Answers will vary depending on how you're doing it (for example, `\hfill` may be what you're looking for).

Comment: @SeanAllred,I've just added the screenshot. I just typed \hfill in mathmode and nothing happened. I will look into what that actually means.

Comment: @egreg, how do I change the meaning? Can you show me how to load a package. Documents -> Settings -> ?

Comment: @TheSubstitute go to Document Settings > Modules and select `Theorems (AMS)`. Click on "Add". To add stuff to the preamble, go to Document Settings > LaTeX Preamble.

Comment: @TheSubstitute, my apologies - I should have been more specific.  I'm asking for something of a graphical MWE -- do you have this text in a figure or float?  Is this text just plain document text (in which case, egreg's comment is the winner)?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}` is the standard way to get a black tombstone instead of a hollow one.

Comment: I don't think we've really got the info we need to answer properly: see all of the comments.